# jQuery submenu dropdown when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I a have a simple menu system and I would like to add functionality to make sub items hide on load until a '+' button is clicked then the submenu slides down.

The menu items are generated through wordpress so I need to add the '+' button if the menu shows the class '.has-dropdown'. I have put together the follow code so far but it's not working:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfwtp5h1/)

```
$( ".clicktodrop" ).insertAfter( ".has-dropdown" );

$(function() {
   $(".clicktodrop").hover(function() {
       $(this).children("ul.dropdown").slideDown(200);
   }, function() {
       $(this).children("ul.dropdown").slideUp(200);
   });
});
```

Hopefully the jsfiddle should show you what I am trying to achieve if the explanation above doesn't make sense! Could anyone see how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $(".clicktodrop").hover(function() {
        $(this).next(".dropdown").slideDown(200);
    }, function() {
        $(this).next(".dropdown").slideUp(200);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c7s8ua3/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! is there anyway to change the hover to click so that the sub menu stays open on mouse out? maybe make the '+' button a toggle so it can open and close the sub menu?

Comment: change `hover` to `toggle`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it hides the '+' button for some reason? Changing it to click also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `next()` instead of `children`:

```
$(this).children("ul.dropdown")
```

should be changed to

```
$(this).next("ul.dropdown")
```

Comment: This drops down both menus for each one hovered